# How to change default user directory to a different drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, user-profiles

How do you change default user directory to a different drive in Windows 7?

I need a **comprehensive** recipe to change ***all*** of the followings.

- Default directory where future user folders are created.
- Other folders typically associated with the account, such as `ProgramData`
- All related system environment variables such as `%USERPROFILE%`.
- Transfer the current user folder and its content to the new directory if possible.

---

To facilitate future answers, here is a subset of the list of things that will need to be changed.

- Everything in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
- `%USERPROFILE%`
- `%PROGRAMFILES%`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`

Comment: You can use hard links, but I hope you know that what you want to achieve is not at all recommended.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is to avoid unnecessary writes on my SSD drive, which is also the system drive. So hard link is still undesirable.

Comment: Not to mention when you make hard link for a lot of directories, the links tend to fail over time.